# Angular (1.5.1) view value not updating

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to update a value in my view with angular 1.5.1 but I can't seem to get it working.

HTML:

```
<section>
  {{ main.state }}
</section>
```

controller:

```
vm.state = 'Scanning face';
test_facial_recognition_score();

function test_facial_recognition_score() {
  var score = vm.webgazer.getTracker().clm.getScore();
  console.log('score: ' + score);
  vm.state = 'Facial detection score: ' + score * 100;
  if(score >= 0.90) {
    recognize_facial_points();
  } else {
    setTimeout(function () {
      test_facial_recognition_score();
    }, 100);
  }
}
```

The initial `vm.state` value is showing correct in my view, also the function `test_facial_recognition_score` is working correct.

console:

```
main.controller.js:25 score: 0.2973043774479575
main.controller.js:25 score: 0.7672696234331723
main.controller.js:25 score: 0.7830798892627874
main.controller.js:25 score: 0.8757129516231377
main.controller.js:25 score: 0.9066341994265908
```

My question: how come the view value (`{{ main.state }}`) won't update the `vm.state` value??

Edit 1:
`{{ main.state }}` is called so because of the stateprovider:

```
$stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',
        controller: 'MainController',
        controllerAs: 'main'
      });
```

Comment: can you show your html fully pls. Why do you call it `{{main.state}}`

Comment: That's my full HTML .__. It's just a small test project so no complicated things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout` doesn't trigger a `$digest` cycle - use Angulars own `$timeout` service:

```
$timeout(test_facial_recognition_score, 100);
```